# Faenza-Darkest icon theme is broken after upgrade to Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: 19.04, icon-themes, faenza

I'm using [Faenza icon theme](https://github.com/shlinux/faenza-icon-theme) on Ubuntu, specifically its Faenza-Darkest version for dark backgrounds (such as Ambiance theme). After upgrading from 18.04 to 19.04 some icons seem broken. Please see the screenshot:

[image]

Instead of beige folder icons, I get these dull grey ones. I tried re-installing Faenza, but its PPA seems to be down and Faenza is missing from the official Ubunbu PPAs.

How can I fix my icon theme?

Answer (score 1):

Rename the file "`folder-symbolic.svg`" in "`/usr/share/icons/Faenza-Dark/places/scalable`" to "`folder-symbolic.svg.old`" or something like that and then it should work again. :)

The trash icon is also wrong, so the best solution is to rename the complete "scalable" folder in "`/usr/share/icons/Faenza-Dark/places/`", so you don't need to rename every single icon that is not working.

Comment: The trash icon is also wrong, so the best solution is to rename the complete "scalable" folder in "/usr/share/icons/Faenza-Dark/places/", so you don't need to rename every single icon that is not working.

Comment: This seems to have fixed the folder icons. But it does not explain why this happens or how to avoid it in the future? Also, some icons are still incorrect, for example the Terminal icon seems to be from some other icon pack.