# Incorrect app icons for some icon themes

Tags: 20.04, icons, gnome-shell, 20.10

Some app icons (but not all) in some icon themes are not being detected/used. For example, if I select Faenza icon theme, icons for Terminal, Rhythmbox, Files and some others seem to not be from Faenza theme, but some other:

[image: Faenza theme displays incorrect icons for Terminal, Rhythmbox, Files etc.]

This is strange because I know for a fact that Faenza does contain icon files for these apps, and also this problem has not existed in the previous versions of Ubuntu (<20.10). The same problem happens with Numix theme.

On the other hand, Numix Circle seems to not suffer from this problem:

[image: Numix Circle seems to display all icons correctly]

I've had a similar, but not identical, [question before](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1138839/faenza-darkest-icon-theme-is-broken-after-upgrade-to-ubuntu-19-04). The work-around from that topic does not help now.

How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, Gnome decided to change icon naming convention. This was done ~3 years ago. The change not only wasn't documented anywhere, but the old documentation still exist and is promoted, as if it was still actual. Sources:

- https://github.com/xenlism/wildfire/issues/49
- https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/-/issues/3076

The only solution possible at this time is to either rename the existing icons, or create symlinks with new names to old icons. That's possible to do by using the bash script from the first link above, or by slightly modifying the `gen.py` script from Numix Core project:

https://github.com/numixproject/numix-core

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see from [its GitHub repository](https://github.com/shlinux/faenza-icon-theme/tree/master/Faenza/apps), it looks like your `scalable` directory has been renamed to `scalable.bkp`. If you change it to the proper name then logout/login, that should resolve your issue.

Hope this helps

Comment: Matigo thanks, but that's not it. I've only renamed the `scalable` directory moments before taking the screenshot, to check if the workaround I've mentioned would work. It didn't. To summarise, the issue persists regardless of whether `scalable` directory has its original name or not.